# Why my 15K SAS HDD drives are so slow?

Tags: performance, dell-poweredge

I have a DELL PE2950 III 2x 3.0GHz Quad Core 32GB RAM.

The card is a Perc 6i SAS dual channel Raid controller w/256mb of cache and BB.
The hard disks are

- 5 x  146GB 15k  3G SAS dell drives  ST3146855SS working independent

testing with hdparm I see the following:

```
/dev/sdb1:
 Timing cached reads:   3858 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1930.17 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 378 MB in  3.01 seconds = 125.39 MB/sec
/dev/sdc1:
 Timing cached reads:   3582 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1792.46 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 374 MB in  3.01 seconds = 124.06 MB/sec*
```

But with a desktop computer with 7.2k seagate baracuda I see:

```
/dev/sdb1:
 Timing cached reads:   12050 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6028.07 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 418 MB in  3.01 seconds = 138.93 MB/sec*
```

So the question
Why do I have so low speed?

Comment: On the "desktop computer" you don't mention its configuration.  Specific information on OS is not provided making analysis problematic.

Comment: Did you clear the internal buffer cache before EACH test?  Not doing this can generate misleading values in hdparam.

Comment: `Timing cached reads` should also be ignored. That's purely benchmarking your system's memory and not the actual drive.

Answer (score 4):

The sustained read specification for this drive is 125MB/s You're getting 124-125MB/s. So you're right where you should be.

> Up to 125-MB/s sustained transfer rate -- [Ad](http://www.scsi4me.com/seagate-st3146855ss-oem.html)

The Barracudas have a higher sustained transfer rate due to their higher areal density but also a slightly higher latency due to their lower spin rate (it takes longer for the data to "come around" to the head).